# How do use datalist with angular and list in combination of key and value when I am using more than value at options

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, web-frontend

I want to pass my Product selected from my datalist to the typescript component variable. I have used previously suggested solutions mentioned where people use one attribute of a data model in the option select. Here I use 3 attribute of that Product model for my option select instead of one:

Here is the model for the product:

```js
export class Product {
    constructor(
      public ID: number,
      public PARTNO: string,
      public CUSTOMER: string,
      public COMPOUNDCODE:string
    ) {}    
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-8">
      <form #imgForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="imageSubmit(imgForm)">
                <div class="row flex">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        list="product_list" 
                        class="form-control form-control-lg col-md-10" 
                        name="product" 
                        id="product" 
                        placeholder="Enter here" 
                        required 
                        ngModel
                        (change)="setSelectedProduct($event.target.value)">
                    <datalist 
                        class="form-control" 
                        id="product_list" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        aria-required="true"
                        hidden 
                    >
                        <option *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index;" (ng)="setProduct($event)" > {{product.PARTNO}}-{{product.CUSTOMER}}-{{product.COMPOUNDCODE}} </option>
                    </datalist>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button 
                            type="button" 
                            (click)="fetchImages()" 
                            class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture">Fetch</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is the image-display.component.ts:

```js
export class ImageDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  products:Product[];
  selectedProduct: Product[];

  settedProduct: Product;

  constructor(private dataManage: DataManagementService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.listProducts();
  }

  private listProducts(){
    console.log('started the page. Gathering Product List');
    this.dataManage.getProducts().subscribe((products: Product[])=>{
      this.products = products;
      //return userList;
    });
  }

  setProduct(event:any){
    this.settedProduct = event;
  }

  setSelectedProduct(prod:string){
    this.selectedProduct = this.products.filter((product)=>product.PARTNO.includes(prod))
    console.log(this.selectedProduct[0].PARTNO);
  }

  fetchImages(){

  }
}
```

I finally want to take the ID of the Product for the fetchimages function. I have tried the previously provided solutions, but in those solutions just a single attribute is used. Whereas here I need to use 3 attribute. The values for the options is being fetched from a FirebirdSQL database and I have no issues in using those values. I am currently having issues in picking out the ID for a product I selected from the datalist.

Comment: AFAIK, this is a limitation in the datalist. I suggest to include the ID in the option like `{{product.ID}}: {{product.PARTNO}}-{{product.CUSTOMER}}-{{product.COMPOUNDCODE}}` then split on the `:` or use a third party component to achieve this

Comment: @yazantahhan Seems like no other way than a workaround, huh. Thanks for that advice